# (Python) Incorrect string value (CP1521 to UTF8)

Tags: python, json, cp1251

There is a problem with .json file, which contains cyrillic symbols. How to convert CP1251 to UTF-8?
(**temp_data.decode('utf-8')** has no effect, such as **ensure_ascii=False** in .dumps)

```
import json

def load_data(filepath):   
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        temp_data = json.load(f)
    return temp_data 


    def pretty_print_json(d):
        out_json = json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators = (',', ': '))
        print(out_json)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("Enter the path to .json file: ") 
        in_path = input()
        print("There are pretty printed json format: ")
        pretty_print_json(load_data(in_path))
```

Comment: What's your issue?  Show a sample data file, desired output, and actual output.

Comment: Data file contains russian words like "ВОДКА" and "БАЛАЛАЙКА", but in result there words are viewing as "/u0439/u0440" etc

Comment: What is the encoding of the data file?  Update your question with the details.  Add a **small** sample of your data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Double_Mind: `'\u0439\u0440' == 'йр'`, so it works fine. Can you post the contents of your file? `print(repr(open(your_filename, 'rb').read()))`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the [ensure_ascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#character-encodings), If `ensure_ascii` is true (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the results are str instances consisting of ASCII characters only. If `ensure_ascii` is false, a result may be a Unicode instance. This usually happens if the input contains Unicode strings or the encoding parameter is used.

Change your code to this:

```
out_json = json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators = (',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
```

And there is a full code:

```
import json

def load_data(filepath):   
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        temp_data = json.load(f)
    return temp_data 


def pretty_print_json(d):
    out_json = json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators = (',', ': '), ensure_ascii=False)
    print(out_json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Enter the path to .json file: ") 
    in_path = raw_input()
    print("There are pretty printed json format: ")
    pretty_print_json(load_data(in_path))
```

I tested [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SmartTeleMax/ru-svg-map/master/examples/data/russia.json) code with this JSON file.

You can see the result in [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/a/397x0q67c7vvlhngrvmoylpx7).

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xab' in position 1328: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Which Python? I tested it with Python3 and worked! and Python2 :) can you give us a sample of your json?

Comment: Python 3.4
It contains cyrillic, as I said. May be there is an issue with my system, I don't know

Comment: @Double_Mind I tasted it by this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SmartTeleMax/ru-svg-map/master/examples/data/russia.json

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Provide a sample of your data file and specify the encoding if your data doesn't:

```
#coding:utf8
import json

datafile_encoding = 'cp1251'  # Any encoding that supports Cyrillic works.

# Create a test file with Cyrillic symbols.
with open('test.json','w',encoding=datafile_encoding) as f:
    D = {'key':'АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТ', 'key2':'АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТ'}
    json.dump(D,f,ensure_ascii=False)

# specify the encoding of the data file
def load_data(filepath):   
    with open(filepath, 'r', encoding=datafile_encoding) as f:
        temp_data = json.load(f)
    return temp_data 

# Use ensure_ascii=False
def pretty_print_json(d):
    out_json = json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, separators = (',', ': '))
    print(out_json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_path = 'test.json'
    pretty_print_json(load_data(in_path))
```

> ```
> {
>     "key": "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТ",
>     "key2": "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТ"
> }
> ```